# Help drawing a circular tikz image on overleaf

Tags: tikz-pgf, asymptote, tkz-euclide, luamplib

Can anyone help to draw this please?

[image]

Comment: Hi, just have you create any code. Any users write to the all user into this site: Will you draw me this picture? Can you tried anything? You can use yourself https://www.mathcha.io/editor

Comment: This site doesn't do well with "please make this picture".  Have you looked through an introduction for drawing in TeX?  Have you tried drawing that diagram?  What parts are you having trouble with?  This doesn't really have anything to do with Overleaf, so we've removed that tag.  And TikZ is a good drawing package, so we've added that tag.  Maybe you can read throuhg a TikZ introduction?

Comment: I guess we can wait a little longer before closing this question (as it is, it will surely be)

Answer (score 2):

Since this is supposed to be a helpful site, here is solution for any one looking for help with simple diagrams.  This is done using [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) wrapped up in `luamplib`.  To get this to compile on Overleaf, you need to choose `LuaLatex` as the compiler option in the menu at the top left.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

    pair A, B, C;
    A = 89 up;
    B = origin;
    C = 144 right;

    draw A--B--C--cycle;

    draw halfcircle scaled abs(A-B) rotated angle (A-B) shifted 1/2[A, B];
    draw halfcircle scaled abs(B-C) rotated angle (B-C) shifted 1/2[B, C];
    draw halfcircle scaled abs(C-A) rotated angle (C-A) shifted 1/2[C, A];

    label.ulft ("$A$", A);
    label.llft ("$B$", B);
    label.lrt  ("$C$", C);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

I hope the code is fairly self-explanatory, but please follow the link at the top for tutorials and other resources.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/semicircle/.style={code={
 \draw (0,0) arc[start angle=180,end angle=360,radius=#1/2];}}]
 \draw (0,3) node[above left]{$A$}
    -- pic[pos=0,sloped]{semicircle=3} (0,0) node[below left]{$B$}
 -- pic[pos=0,sloped]{semicircle=4}  (4,0) node[below right]{$C$}
  --  pic[pos=0,sloped,scale=-1]{semicircle=5}  cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course one could also make the computation of the radii automatic e.g. using `calc`.

Answer (score 1):

```
With tkz-euclide and Tikz !

\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/B,4/0/C,0/3/A}
\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
\tkzDrawSemiCircle[diameter](C,B)
\tkzDrawSemiCircle[diameter](B,A)
\tkzDrawSemiCircle[diameter](A,C)
\tkzLabelPoint(C){$C$}
\tkzLabelPoint[above left](A){$A$}
\tkzLabelPoint[below left](B){$B$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]