# Need help with finishing a picture using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\geometry{verbose}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
\draw[thick] (0,0) -- (0,3) -- (4,0)-- (0,0); 
\filldraw[thick, fill=white] (0,3) arc (90:270: 1.5);
\filldraw[thick, fill=white] (0,0) arc (180:360: 2);
\filldraw[black] (0,0) node[below left] {$B$};
\filldraw[black] (0,3) node[above left] {$A$};
\filldraw[black] (4,0) node[anchor=west] {$C$};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have this so far to make the triangle and label the points but how do you draw the semicircles??

Comment: Welcome! An almost identical question has been asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/541194/194703) a couple of hours ago.

Answer (score 2):

I will be happy to delete this but since I had this slight extension of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/541219/194703) on my machine I could also just post it. This defines a style for the `semicircle` that measures the length and angle of the path and puts the arc accordingly. If you want it to be on the other side of the path, add `yscale=-1`.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9,pics/semicircle/.style={code={
 \draw (0,0) arc[start angle=180,end angle=0,radius=#1/2];}},
 semicircled/.style={to path={let \p1=(\tikztostart),
  \p2=(\tikztotarget),\n1={veclen(\x1-\x2,\y1-\y2)},
  \n2={atan2(\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1)} in 
  (\p1) pic[rotate=\n2,transform shape]{semicircle=\n1}
  }},bullet/.style={fill,inner sep=1.2pt,circle}]
  %
  \draw (0,3) node[bullet,label=above left:{$A$}](A){}
    -- (0,0) node[bullet,label=below left:{$B$}](B){}
    edge[semicircled] (A)
    --  (4,0) node[bullet,label=below right:{$C$}](C) {}
    edge[semicircled] (B)
    edge[semicircled,yscale=-1] (A)
  --cycle;
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I just need one more semicircle, can you please help finish that tilted semicircle

Comment: @AngelBrunch This result has all the semicircles of your screen shot. How would I know which additional semicircle you want?

Comment: I edited my code again

Comment: it is the one on the top right. My code has now two semicircles

Comment: @AngelBrunch In your code you can add `\filldraw[thick, fill=white] (4,0) arc ({-atan2(3,4)}:{-atan2(3,4)+180}: 2.5);`.

Comment: thank u so much!!!!!